# Toggle AppleShowAllFiles with a simple bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Preface: I am a complete bash noob.

I want to write a simple script to toggle AppleShowAllFiles on my mac.

I am thinking something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#toggle AppleShowAllFiles

if defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles == TRUE
then
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
else 
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
fi

killall Finder
```

That doesn't seem to be working, but I am sure one of you could bash it out in 1 second flat; please commence bashing and help a lost soul!

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#toggle AppleShowAllFiles

current_value=$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)
if [ $current_value = "TRUE" ]
then
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
else
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
fi

killall Finder
```

The `if` syntax of your script was a bit...well, iffy. That's all that needed to be changed.

Comment: `-eq` is a numeric comparison. Also, parentheses like that are `csh` syntax, not Bash, etc.

Comment: Fixed those two issues. For the record, the script still worked before that.

Comment: Excellent! thank you so much for that. Is there any reason to first declare that current_value  var, or would the following still be acceptable form: if [ `defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles` = "TRUE" ]

Comment: I assigned it to a variable for cleanliness. If you wanted to keep in on one line, you need to put the command inside backticks (``) in order for it to work.

Comment: Ope.. the commenting stripped my apostrophe of the first part of the predicate. Also.. what is the significance of that strange apostrophe that is wrapping the first part of the predicate? the diagonal apostrophe that is on the tilde key..? Does that evaluate whatever is inside it?

Comment: haha, you just answered my question.. "backtick" is what that is called.. thanks again!

Comment: You're right, it evaluates what is inside them (they are called backticks) and then treats it as if it was a variable assigned to whatever the command outputs.

Comment: @CarterAllen: It's ***very unlikely*** to have worked in Bash. `if ($current_value -eq "TRUE")` says to run, in a subshell, a command contained in a variable (which would be `TRUE` or `FALSE`) with the option(s) `-eq` and argument `TRUE`. Since neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE` are standard commands or utilities, the result would *almost certainly* be an error message.

Comment: I've updated the script in my answer to use the $() syntax instead of backticks after reading the article linked by Dennis in the comments of another answer. I love it when answering a question makes *me* learn something too.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
if [[ $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) == TRUE ]]
```

Comment: +1 for showing me another way to phrase the predicate. Helpful for my newbosity.

Comment: @James: It's much [better to use `$()`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) than backticks.

Comment: Ahh yes, from the looks of that post it is indeed. It also feels more like what I'm used to from other languages. Thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 0):

Show Hidden Files on your Mac

Launch the Terminal and enter these commands exactly as shown.
The first command activates the ability to see the hidden files:

defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

Now you must relaunch the Finder by killing it, this is how the changes take effect:

killall Finder